# PHP Session variables in java

Tags: java, php, http, session

In my server-client model I'm using java for client side and for server side scripting using php5.

For communication I'm using simple http protocol.

In server I have some $SESSION variables(in php). I want access these variables in my java client.

How can it be posssible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is JavaScript and not Java!

Comment: How can a web developer not know the difference between javascript and java?

Comment: See...I am making my own client in java. (I'm not using browser)

Comment: @adarshr - I'm asking for JAVA solution...
@Richard - yup,how can a web developer not know the difference between javascript and java?!! he should know as I know the diffrence...

Comment: @Abhishek - I think you should rephrase your question and explain clearly that you're not using a web browser as a client. Most of us will assume that it is in the context of a browser.

Comment: Could you please define "Most of us"?? If I write "JAVA" that means it is java...And though I am new to stackoverflow I know what is the ratio of java questions to javascript question. In my question I have written "..I'm using java for client side.." clearly.

Comment: Yes but what you're running into here is the novice issue - There are a lot of ppl who write "I'm using Java for the client-side" and actually mean JS. I'm not saying you're wrong - clearly you aren't, but you're not being explicit enough to rise above the noise :) Anyway, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK session variables is a server-side variables, that can be accessed by session id. You must refactor you application (to make java-client free of server side information) or send them (variables) from server to client manually.

Comment: sure, I mean pure java-client. Not javascript.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit "AFAIK session variables" or u can give any link regarding that?

Comment: AFAIK is an acronym meaning "as far as I know."

Comment: @Richard Pianka - thnks .I thought it wud some kind of API library :P

Comment: Explain the problem that you have. May be we can find solution that will work. Think yourself: if session variables on server can be accessed by remote client without any problems than you have a LARGE security hole in your app.

Comment: One other obervation - Sessions are used to store information that can't securely or usefully be sent back and forth with every HTTP request - hence by definition, they're only available server-side. If you want the client to access them, make them cookies and save the server memory. You also avoid session timeout issues

Answer (score 2):

You should use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) instead of session variables if you're planning on sending it to the client side.

Comment: He's actually talking about a java application and not a browser environment

Comment: Actually, server side scripting is done.I have used there SESSION variables..So it wont be possible to change all the code right now.

Comment: @JohnP I never said he was using a browser and considering he's using http, he can still use cookies.  Don't assume that I'm assuming something.

Comment: @JohnP - in java client also we can handle cookie.
@Richard - you are correct

Comment: @Richard I'm sorry, I misunderstood your reply. And seeing the OPs comment he can use cookies on the client side. @Richard, could you just edit your reply so I can take back my downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Your Java-client will make requests to the server, and the server will act like a web service, right?

If so, include all/any $_SESSION variables you might need with the XML/json/whatever response that the server sends back to the clients, something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reply>
  <request>
    <method>getUsers</method>
    <param name="page">1</param>
    <param name="apiKey">API_KEY</param>
    <param name="sessId">SESSION_ID</param>
  </request>
  <response>
    <status>
      <code>0</code>
      <message>OK</message>
    </status>
    <users>
      <!-- Request reply here -->
    </users>
    <session>
      <variable1>$_SESSION['var1']</variable1>
      <!-- Additional session variables you might need on the client here[...] -->
    </session>
  </response>
</reply>
```

The thing is, session variables are something the server uses to keep track of which client is accessing it now, and relate data to that particular client. If you need this information on the client, perhaps you could refactor the application to create this data on the client and pass it to the server in case the server needs that data?

Comment: Got the point and many thanks for understanding my question (many ppl down voted my question :()

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var variable = '<?php echo $SESSION["variable_name"];?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not making a webpage.I'm making my own java client.So your javascript code wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to understand is that session variables has no difference from any other PHP variable.
Thus, you have to request it from PHP as well.
Of course, supplying a request with session identifier got from the previous calls. That's all, not a rocket science.

Comment: I see what you mean but "session variables has no difference from any other PHP variable." whilst accurate for the current question is actually wildly inaccurate. I'm sure you know this but you may want to put some scope on your answer :)